# Why is Omnifaces Websocket <o:socket> not working with Websphere 9?

Tags: java, websocket, websphere, omnifaces

I have a test app created base on the Omniface socket demo (http://showcase.omnifaces.org/push/socket) for a counter that increments as it is clicked and it's working on Tomcat 8.5, somehow when I deployed to Webphere 9 server this is not working.

In Websphere 9, I get this error when I do view source in the browser.

`<script type="text/javascript" id="j_id_h">Error 500: javax.servlet.ServletException: o:socket endpoint is not enabled. You need to set web.xml context param &#39;org.omnifaces.SOCKET_ENDPOINT_ENABLED&#39; with value &#39;true&#39;.`

Above error is from the line `<o:socket` in PushBean.xhtml:

`<o:socket channel="counter" onmessage="updateCounter" onclose="onclosePush" connected="#{pushBean.connected}" />`

I can tell the `<o:socket>` tag is not working and I've enabled the socket endpoint in web.xml, see below web.xml file.

Web.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
      <display-name>WebSocketServerJSFOmni</display-name>
      <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
      </welcome-file-list>
      <context-param>
        <param-name>org.omnifaces.SOCKET_ENDPOINT_ENABLED</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
      </context-param>
      <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
      </servlet>
      <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
      </servlet-mapping>
    </web-app>
```

PushBean.java

```
    package org.omnifaces.showcase.push;

    import java.io.Serializable;
    import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;

    import javax.inject.Inject;
    import javax.inject.Named;

    import org.omnifaces.cdi.Push;
    import org.omnifaces.cdi.PushContext;
    import org.omnifaces.cdi.ViewScoped;

    @Named
    @ViewScoped
    public class PushBean implements Serializable {

        private static AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();

        private boolean connected;

        @Inject @Push(channel="counter")
        private PushContext push;

        public void toggle() {
            connected = !connected;
        }

        public void increment() {
            long newvalue = counter.incrementAndGet();
            push.send(newvalue);
        }

        public boolean isConnected() {
            return connected;
        }

        public Long getCount() {
            return counter.get();
        }

    }
```

PushBean.xhtml

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
        xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
        xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
        xmlns:o="http://omnifaces.org/ui"
        xmlns:of="http://omnifaces.org/functions">

    <h:head>
    </h:head>

    <body>

        <h3>Global counter</h3>
        <p>
            Below is a static counter which has the same value application wide.
        </p>

        <h1><h:panelGroup id="count">#{pushBean.count}</h:panelGroup></h1>

        <h:form>
            <p>
                If you enable the push, then a websocket will be opened.
                Note that it's by default always auto-connected when included in the page, but for demo purposes we're initially disabling it.
            </p>
            <p>
                <h:panelGroup id="toggle">
                    Push is #{pushBean.connected ? 'connected' : 'disconnected'} 
                    <h:commandButton value="#{pushBean.connected ? 'disconnect' : 'connect'} it" action="#{pushBean.toggle}">
                        <f:ajax render="toggle increment :count"/>
                    </h:commandButton>
                </h:panelGroup>
            </p>
            <p>
                If push is connected and you press the "increment!" button, then the static counter will increment in bean and the push will send out the new value to the same channel in all connected clients.
                To see it yourself, open the same page in multiple tabs/windows/browsers/machines and trigger the push in only one of it.
                Note that the counter also won't increment from other side if push is still disconnected on current page.
            </p>
            <p>
                <h:commandButton id="increment" value="increment!" action="#{pushBean.increment}" disabled="#{not pushBean.connected}">
                    <f:ajax />
                </h:commandButton>
            </p>
        </h:form>


        <!-- NOTE: having inline script in XHTML like below is bad practice. -->
        <!-- It's included directly in XHTML just for sake of demo. -->
        <!-- In real world code, put it in a JS file :) -->

        <script>
            function updateCounter(newvalue) {
                //$("#count").text(newvalue);
                document.getElementById("count").innerHTML = newvalue;
            }

            function onclosePush(code) {
                if (code == -1) {
                    alert("Oops! Your browser doesn't seem to support web sockets. The push functionality won't work.")
                }
                else if (code != 1000) {
                    alert("Oops! Push has stopped working with error code " + code + "! Reload the page.")
                }
            }
        </script>

        <!-- End of bad practice ;) -->


        <o:socket channel="counter" onmessage="updateCounter" onclose="onclosePush" connected="#{pushBean.connected}" />


    </body>
    </html>
```

`<o:socket>` should be transformed to JavaScript which it is not doing it on Websphere 9 server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For WAS 9 i had to explicitly register the listener in web.xml before the StartupServletContextListener.

https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/issues/502

```
<listener>
        <listener-class>org.omnifaces.ApplicationListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the omnifaces.jar not in the general server lib, is neccesary locale the library in the project lib.

With that action, the context starts first and after omnifaces

[For more information check here](https://balusc.omnifaces.org/2013/10/how-to-install-cdi-in-tomcat.html)